# GridBagLayout why is the third column bigger?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to make the buttons equaly wide and together they should be as wide as the JTextField above them.
code:

```
window.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gb = new GridBagConstraints();

gb.gridx = 0;
gb.gridy = 0;
gb.gridwidth = 3;
gb.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gb.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
window.add(text,gb); //adds JTextField

gb.gridwidth = 1;
gb.gridy++;
window.add(one,gb); //adds JButton
gb.gridx++;
window.add(two,gb); //adds JButton
gb.gridx++;
window.add(three,gb); //adds JButton
```

[image: Screenshot]

When I use `gb.gridwidth = GridBagConstriants.RELATIVE;` this happens:

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **gb.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;** tells the GridBagLayout to allocate all remaining space to the last element in the row.

Comment: [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: When using `gb.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;` the problem persists, but in a different way (look 2. screenshot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieved this by setting `GridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0` for buttons.

Another key thing to notice is that I have added text field and buttons to a `JPanel` and then added that `JPanel` to the content pane of `JFrame`. I have not added text field and buttons directly to the content pane.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class EqualWidthButtons
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints gb = new GridBagConstraints();
    gb.gridx = 0;
    gb.gridy = 0;
    gb.gridwidth = 3;
    gb.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    panel.add(new JTextField(20), gb);

    gb.gridwidth = 1;
    gb.gridy++;
    gb.weightx = 1.0; // This is the important line
    panel.add(new JButton("1"), gb);

    gb.gridx++;
    panel.add(new JButton("2"), gb);

    gb.gridx++;
    panel.add(new JButton("3"), gb);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, new GridBagConstraints());
    frame.setBounds(300, 200, 400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. But, I have a few questions: **1.** I don't really understand what weightx does even after I read about it in the documentation and I would appreciate if you could explain what it does. **2.** Why did you use `frame.getContentPane().add()` instead of simply writing `frame.add()`?

Comment: @Marian, 1. `weightx` and `weighty` specifies how "extra" space is distributed among cells in the grid. Let's say total available width is 100 pixels. And we want to show 3 buttons ("A", "B", "C") each has a width of 20 pixels. So, remaining extra width is 40 (i.e. 100 - 20*3). Now if we specify `weightx` for 3 buttons as 1, 1, and 0 respectively, only "A" and "B" buttons will get extra space (20 pixels each). So, the final outcome is "A" has 40 pixels, "B" has 40 pixels and "C" has 20 pixels for their cells.

Comment: @Marian, 2. For `JFrame`, `getContentPane().add()` and `add()` leads to the same result. Either way, the component is added to the content pane of `JFrame`. Since I prefer `frame.getContentPane().add()`, I use that :)